# sqlcmd works in CMD and not in bash

Tags: sql-server, bash, sqlcmd

I am having quite a few problems making `MSSQL` drivers work in Ubuntu. I have followed the following [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to make `sqlcmd` work in `Ubuntu 16.04`.

```bat
# In CMD:
sqlcmd -S my_server_name -U my_username -P my_password -d my_database
1> select name from sys.databases
2> go
```

After installing the same tool in Ubuntu, it seems to work, but it timeouts when attempting to connect to the same database:

```bat
# In Ubuntu bash
sqlcmd -S my_server_name -U my_username -P my_password -d my_database
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AFA.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

I have tried to change configurations of the database, such that the port is static at `1433`, but still no luck.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you ping my_server_name from Ubuntu?

Comment: I have tried to nc -v my_server_name 1433, but it does not connect.

Comment: `0x2AFA` is `IP_DEST_NET_UNREACHABLE` / `IP_DEST_NO_ROUTE`. I expect a simple `ping` should fail as well (i.e. not `sqlcmd` specific, it just can't get to `my_server_name` from that machine).

Comment: Apparantly Ubuntu forces you to specify the ip-adress of the server, while windows doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem!

#### 1. Install MSSQL drivers on Ubuntu

Follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

#### 2. Ensure your port on the database is static

Follow [this tutorial](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62165/i-cant-connect-to-my-servers-sql-database-via-an-ip-address) to set up a static port.

#### 3. Identify the IP adress of your database

I had to call the following code on the database to get the ip-adress: local_net_address.

```
SELECT  
+    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('net_transport') AS net_transport,
+             CONNECTIONPROPERTY('protocol_type') AS protocol_type,
+             CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS auth_scheme,
+             CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address,
+             CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS local_tcp_port,
+             CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') AS client_net_address
```

#### 4. Connect to database (in Ubuntu bash)

Here are two examples with netcat and sqlcmd.

```
# Using MSSQL tool
sqlcmd -S my_server_ip_adress//my_server_name,my_port -U my_username -P my_password -d my_database

# Using netcat
nc -z -v -w5 my_server_ip_adress my_port
```

Comment: Alternatively, UDP port 1434 may be unreachable or the SQL Browser service isn't started. If either of these is the case, you can't connect to a non-default instance, or an instance not listening on port 1433. Local connections will not be thus constrained. Alternatively, `my_server_name` does not resolve properly in DNS.